# i need help moving a string from one class to another class in another namespace

Tags: c#

im new to programming and im currently working on something and i need to move a string from one class to another, someone suggested that i can use objects but after a lot of research i still cannot find a way to succesfully pass a string from one class to another.

`class 1` has the string that i later on need in `class 2`

```
Class 1
{
  string A = "james";
  string B = "jack";
}
```

```
Class 2
{
  // this is the class were i need A and B
}
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19480747/share-variable-between-multiple-classes) answer your question?

Comment: First read about `static` and normal variables then decide what you want to do. Static variables can be accessed directly through class name but there is only one instance of that variable while normal variables are connected with objects which are initialized with specific class.

Comment: Question becomes why does class 2 need info from class 1, would it not just take a reference to the class one instance?

Comment: @LarsVanDeKamp What do you call *moving*? Passing as parameters to a method or inherit variables like with Animal having legs and Cat being an Animal having legs? Or do you talk about composition/aggregation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a class like this

```
public class Dummy{
  public string firstName {get;set;}
  public string lastName {get;set;}
}
```

From your class 1, you will have the data

```
class First{
  public Dummy GetData(){
    var dummy = new Dummy(){
    firstName = "james",
    lastName = "jack"
   };
 return dummy;
  }
}

class Second{
 var first = new First();
 var myData = first.GetData();
 Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mydata);
}
```

the `mydata` will have your information from `Class 1`